# How to add a dimension using reshape layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to expand dimension in my model. Can I replace
***tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)),***
with a   ***tf.keras.layers.Reshape()*** layer

My model is

```
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(i1,i2))),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

I want to replace the lambda layer

Modified Code:

```
 tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, activation='relu'),input_shape=(i1,i2)),
tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

Error :

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape" (type Reshape).

total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [20], output_shape = [1]

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 20), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Yes..why not? Or what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not sure about the inputs of the reshape layer which expands dimension of axis = 1

Comment: PreCondition is not to use lambda layer

Comment: @AloneTogether : I have added the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (you do not have to take care of the batch dimension):

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((2, ))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,) + x.shape[1:])(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

With your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((5, 10))
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, activation='relu'))(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,) + x.shape[1:])(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

Generally, if you check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape), the output shape of the last layer will be inferred if you use `-1`:

```
# also supports shape inference using `-1` as dimension
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 2, 2)))
# where 2 and 2 are the new dimensions and -1 is referring to the output shape of the last layer.
```

This essentially works, because the `Reshape` [layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/layers/reshaping/reshape.py#L115) is internally calling `tf.TensorShape`:

```
input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
```

I personally prefer calling the shape explicitly though.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, -1))`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape) like below, instead of using `tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1))`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, activation='relu', input_shape=[100, 256])),
        tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, -1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])
model(tf.random.uniform((1, 100, 256))) # (batch_dim, input.shape[0], input.shape[1])
model.summary()
```

---

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectio  (1, 20)                  21360     
 nal)                                                            
                                                                 
 reshape_1 (Reshape)         (1, 1, 20)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (1, 1, 10)                210       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 21,570
Trainable params: 21,570
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Check your code and we get the same result:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, activation='relu', input_shape=[100, 256])),
        tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])
model(tf.random.uniform((1, 100, 256))) # (batch_dim, input.shape[0], input.shape[1])
model.summary()
```

---

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 bidirectional_2 (Bidirectio  (1, 20)                  21360     
 nal)                                                            
                                                                 
 lambda (Lambda)             (1, 1, 20)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (1, 1, 10)                210       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 21,570
Trainable params: 21,570
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```